# How would one 'build' embedded documents in mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Trying to create embedded documents for a collection. However, I am finding this approach a bit inefficient and long-coming. Is there a better way to do something like:

```
@stat.dates.find_or_create_by(date: 20130904).users.find_or_create_by(status: 'signed_in').update_attributes(count: 1234)
```

I am aware there is an `autobuild` directive. But this only applies for `embeds_one` and `has_one` associations.

Any other approaches?

Comment: Is dates embedded on stat? is users embedded on date? can u post your models so i can have a better idea of the question. thanks

Comment: Yes, dates embedded in stat, users embedded in date